# AWS account A lambda trying to trigger ecs run task for B account

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

code in lambda function -

```
String arn = "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:accountId(B-account):task-definition/task-defn-name";
        
String cluster="arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:accountId(B-account):cluster/cluster name"; 
       
RunTaskRequest request = new RunTaskRequest().withLaunchType(LaunchType.EC2).withCluster(cluster).withTaskDefinition(arn);
        
 final STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider cross_acct_lambda = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("AccountB-Role", "cross_acct_lambda").build();
        RunTaskResult response = AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(cross_acct_lambda).build().runTask(request);
```

This worked i was using default credential provider  instead STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider

Permission policy in Account B role

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:RunTask",
                "ecs:Describe*",
                "ecs:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
```

Trust relationship of Role in B account

```
"Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountId-Aaccount:role/ecsLambdaRole"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

A- Account role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AccountId-Baccount:role/role name"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this directly as you are attempting.

Usually, cross-account operations are enabled through  [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

For this to work in your use-case you would have to do the following:

1. Setup an **assumable role in AccB**. The role would have a policy with permissions to start its ecs task. The trust relationship would allow AccA to assume the role.
2. A **lambda execution role in AccA** would have permissions to assume the role from AccB (i.e. `sts:AssumeRole`).
3. The lambda would use STS service to explicitly **assume the role**. The call to STS would return temporary IAM credentials. The credentials would allow you to create a session in your lambda function to **trigger ECS** tasks in AccB.

How to assume the role in lambda from AccB is explained in the following **AWS blog post**:

- [How can I configure a Lambda function to assume a role from another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to mention this is been already done despite that am still getting an error.

Comment: @pravinbhogil  Hi. You would have to update the question, or make new one with the new version of the code (how do you assume the role?), role details and new error messages. Otherwise, its difficult to speculate without knowing what is the new state of your application after adding all the roles and changing lambda code to use them.